# To access both Images and Video in Gallery when accessed through an external application in Lollipop

Tags: android, image, video, android-5.0-lollipop, android-gallery

I'm working in an application, in which I can post the images and videos from my Gallery. But since when Android Lollipop was released I'm unable to see my videos in my gallery when accessed through my own application, which makes me unable to post my videos. The code is working fine with all other Android Versions.

Can anyone suggest some idea of how to view both Images and Videos in my gallery through android coding, especially for Lollipop version.

I see that this flaw has been rectified in Instagram. So can anyone help me in solving this issue...!